# How to use "SPContext.Current.Web.Url" in client object model?

Tags: client-object-model

When working with server side code we can use the following line to obtain the url of the current web site:

```
var url = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;
```

How can we do the same when working with the client object model?

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE: Shankar's comment is correct, my post does not really answer the original question. I must have misread it at the time. I leave my post for completeness but the other answers are the correct ones.**

---

The Client Object Model (CSOM) equivalent to the SPContext is the ClientContext. However since CSOM is a remote API there is no current context (unless you are working with client-side code), you need to tell SharePoint the context by supplying the Site URL.

```
var siteUrl = "http://sp2013found/sites/demo";
using (var context = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
    var web = context.Web;
    context.Load(web);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    ResultsListBox.Items.Add(web.Title);
}
```

When working with client-side code there is a current context because the code is running in a page that was generated by SharePoint.

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
context.load(web);
context.executeQueryAsync(success, fail);

function success() {
    var message = jQuery("#message");
    message.text(web.get_title());
}

function fail(sender, args) {
    alert("Call failed. Error: " +
        args.get_message());
}
```

Comment: this answer completely misses the question. ClientContext code shown above does not show how to get the Url. I have tried, web.Url property is not initialized after doing context.Load(web); context.ExecuteQuery(); web.Title is one of the very few properties initialized and available. vote -1.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using client side code within a site, you can pull the URL real fast using

`_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl`

Comment: Only once the page is loaded. Inside JSLink, this will not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  That is server object model code. The object you should look at is ClientContext.

Even if you could use `SPContext` in Client Object Model code it would be null, so why bother?

Answer (score 0):

In CSOM C# you can use

```
var url = clientContext.Web.Url;
```

Comment: for you downvoters - Ive found this answer works, but you need to load the Web first with `clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web)` followed by a `clientContext.ExecuteQuery()`